# Unity3d 5.3.3 Rigidbody2d velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm learning Unity 3D and working on a 2d space shooter.  I'm trying to create a system where a power up ability will randomly drop from a destroyed enemy.

Right now what I'm trying to do is before the enemy destroys itself, it calls a function on the power up object.  Ideally, the enemy will pass it's translate position so the power object can snap to it, and then "fall" from that point.  Problem is, right now trying to apply a velocity to the power up object when the enemy is destroyed does not work.

This is the method on the Enemy object that calls the Power Up's method when it's being destroyed:

```
void DropPowerUp(){
    PowerUp.GetComponent<PowerUp>().DropPowerUp(transform.position);
    PowerUpReady = false;
}
```

This is the DropPowerUp method on the Power Up object:

```
public void DropPowerUp(Vector3 enemyLoc){
    print("power up dropped");
    this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector3(0, -3f, 0);
}
```

If I just do a test and have the velocity applied to the power up object in it's Start method, it'll work fine.  The power up will just drop down as intended.  And right now, the function is being called by the enemy because I can see that print statement in the console.  But for some reason, I cannot apply the velocity to the power up object from within that method.  Any thoughts on why this might not be working??  Thanks!

Comment: apart from anything else, it's not "this.".  As a (broad general) rule, never use "this" in Unity.  it's a common mistake from experienced OO programmers.  Unity is ECS and has little to do with OO.  you likely want `gameObject.GetComponent...`

Comment: in your second code fragment, you do not actually use "enemyLoc" at all.  it is very hard to help unless you post complete code.  if you just forgot to set `transform.position = enemyLoc;` then that's the solution.

Comment: i notice you have "PowerUp" and "PowerUpReady" as Upper case.  It is very unlkely this is correct.  variables must be "lowerCase" like that.  "finalEnemy" "timerUnit" and so on.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the reply. I was ignoring the transform.position for now just to see if I could get the velocity to work.  I just placed the power up on screen to see if this function would work.  I changed the code to read gameObject.GetComponent as you suggested and it still didn't work.  I also realize that I have some confusing names..I can try renaming the variables to make sure I'm not calling the wrong ones.

Comment: ok. once you do all that really you'd have to post ALL your code so folks can guess what is going wrong if anything. cheers

Comment: Yeah, there's so many lines of logic in there.. checking for things to happen, that I thought I'd simplify it when asking.  So I think I will just do a test case with two objects and and try and repro the problem there, and then post the code from that test casse if it doesn't work.  Thanks again!

Comment: You shouldn't use direct attribution to your velocity, instead you may use Rigidbody2D.AddForce() (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html) or a Constant Force (http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ConstantForce2D.html). Also, I couldn't understand how you are instantiating your PowerUp object, now looking at your code it seems just a component on your enemy object and not a GameObject at the scene. It is a child of your enemy or where it is on the scene hierarchy when you try to call it's "Drop" function?

Comment: right; it's hopeless without all the code shown here.